# Getting Started With Rails Tutorial: 5.7 Showing posts -- No Forbidden Attributes Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

I've been following this Rails tutorial:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Section 5.7 tells me that I should expect an ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError

The thing is, I don't get the error. It works without the permit keyword.

My create method looks like this:

```
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  end
```

I'm working with Rails 4.0 and Ruby 2.0. Any idea why the strong parameters security function isn't working?

Comment: can you please post your Post model code here also?

Comment: with rails 4 there are some changes on how to allow params, http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation is actually misleading, you're right.

If you coded your controller as shown in chapter 5.6

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

  @post.save
  redirect_to @post
end

private
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
 end
```

you're already permitting the use of the parameters `title` and `text`.

The next chapter (5.7) assumes you didn't use the `permit`-method already.

If you'd change Line 2 to:

```
 @post = Post.new(post_params)
```

as seen in the screenshot, the error will be thrown. Additionally, the 'fix' in chapter 5.7 doesn't define a new private method `post_params` as you did, but applies the fix inline.

```
@post = Post.new(params[:post].permit(:title, :text))
```

Answer (score 2):

By Any chance do you have this code in your posts_controller:

```
private
 def post_params
   params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
 end
```

according to the new security measure conventions in rails 4
  http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters
  if you have this , that means you are permitting to use those params to be used in the creation and updation of models.

and as you said you are following this tutorial
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#saving-data-in-the-controller

you have this code in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

Doh... followed the documentation word for word -- yes, it is misleading.

The permit is already in the post_params method:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :text)
end
```

Comment: now you(and me) will never forget how to permit params for update and create.. this will stick for lifetime :)